# How to write a loop in assembly for the or1k architecture

Tags: loops, assembly, processor

I am running an assembly code on a platform that consist of OR1k processor and its peripherals. I want to run the code a bit longer by inserting a loop into it.
How to insert a loop into this code? For instance, If I want the two Lines of the ADDI to run 50 times, How to do that ?
Can anyone help ?

My code is:

```
 .global _start
 _start:        

  l.addi        r1,r2,0
  l.addi        r1,r2,1

 .global exit
  exit:
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use CMP & JNE commands.
try using this code:

```
MOV x,0
F: ADD x,01H
l.addi        r1,r2,0
l.addi        r1,r2,1
CMP x,50
JNE F:
```

Comment: An 8bit variable
you can also use INC x instead of F: ADD x,01H